# MySQL member of several teams

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables: users, active_users and teams.

```
users: id, name
active_users: userId, teamId
teams: id, name
```

active_users "links" users and teams together so that a user can belong to more than one team, and teams can have multiple users.

Say that I have 5 teams with id from 1-5

What is the best way to write a query that shows only the users that belongs to team 1, 2 and 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to approach these questions using `group by` and `having`.  So, here is one way:

```
select au.userId
from active_users au
where au.teamId in (1, 2, 4)
group by au.userId
having count(*) = 3;
```

This assumes that `active_users` has no duplicates.  If it does, then you will need `count(distinct)` in the `having` clause.

Comment: Thats an interesting solution. having count(*) = 3, is the part I couldn't figure out myself. I'll try and put this into my slightly more complex SQL and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: @user1695602: `count(distinct au.teamId)`.